# Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id on Yith social login wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

Anyone can help me to solve this problem? I am using yith woocommerce social login plugin on my wordpress. I tried to implement login via facebook and g+. While using g+ login it's successfully work, but while using facebook there is no response and my page just reload my page and append this

```
#_=_
```

character into my url.

plugins/yith-woocommerce-social-login/logs/log.txt show report below

> Hybrid_Auth initialize: A stored Error found, Throw an new Exception
>   and delete it from the store: Error#5, 'Authentication failed!
>   Facebook returned an invalid user id.' --

wp_content/debug.log show report below

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function authenticate() on null in
>   /wp-content/plugins/yith-woocommerce-social-login/includes/class-yith-social-login.php
>   on line 156

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solve it by changing these lines:

\wp-content\plugins\yith-woocommerce-social-login\includes\hybridauth\Hybrid\Providers\Facebook.php: **27**

```
public $scope = ['email'];
```

and

\wp-content\plugins\yith-woocommerce-social-login\includes\hybridauth\Hybrid\Providers\Facebook.php: **85**

```
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken("https://[your-domain]/wp-content/plugins/yith-woocommerce-social-login/includes/hybridauth/?hauth_done=Facebook");
```

And

https://[your-domain]/wp-content/plugins/yith-woocommerce-social-login/includes/hybridauth/?hauth_done=Facebook must be registered in Valid OAuth Redirect URIs  in FB administration